# SliverList and Getx StateMixin support

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, flutter-getx

I'm struggling trying to make a `GetxController` work with a `SliverList`. In particular, my controller returns the view state with `StateMixin` from [Getx library](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx#state-management).

```dart
class ItinerariesByCreatorPageController extends GetxController
    with StateMixin<Pair<Creator, List<Itinerary>>> {
  ItinerariesByCreatorPageController(this._interactor);

  final ItinerariesInteractor _interactor;

  void getCreatorPage(String creatorSlug, String language) {
    _interactor
        .getItinerariesByCreatorSlug(creatorSlug, language)
        .then((value) => change(value, status: RxStatus.success()))
        .onError<String>((error, stackTrace) =>
            change(null, status: RxStatus.error(error.toString())));
  }
}
```

On the view side, I'm using `obx` extension to observe the controller state and a `SliverList` to display data. Unfortunately, `SliverList` delegate `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` needs to provide list `childCount` in its constructor, but the child count comes asynchronously from the controller and I can't find a way on the Getx documentation to return the child count in a reactive way. Is there any way to make `SliverList` and `Getx` work together?

```dart
Widget _getItinerariesList() {
    return SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) => _controller.obx((data) {
                  if (index == 0) {
                    return CreatorInfoWidget(
                      creator: data.first,
                      imageWidget: CreatorImageWidget(
                        imageUrl: data.first.avatars.first,
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (index == 1) {
                    return MainItineraryWidget(
                        creator: data.first, itinerary: data.second[index - 1]);
                  } else {
                    return SecondaryItineraryWidget(
                        creator: data.first, itinerary: data.second[index - 1]);
                  }
                }),
            childCount: 5 // use a dynamic child count here, coming from the controller));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move up `controller.obx` above the `SliverList`

```
Widget _getItinerariesList() {
return _controller.obx((data) {
  return SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index){
              if (index == 0) {
                return CreatorInfoWidget(
                  creator: data.first,
                  imageWidget: CreatorImageWidget(
                    imageUrl: data.first.avatars.first,
                  ),
                );
              } else if (index == 1) {
                return MainItineraryWidget(
                    creator: data.first, itinerary: data.second[index - 1]);
              } else {
                return SecondaryItineraryWidget(
                    creator: data.first, itinerary: data.second[index - 1]);
              }
            }),
        childCount: data.yourCountVariable // use a dynamic child count here, coming from the controller));
   }
}
```